# Unable to install ExchangeCdo with Outlook 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, bes

We recently got the Blackberry Express Server for our small home business and linked it in with our Exchange 2010 server. All is well except for calendar syncing. From what I can tell I require the ExchangeCdo patch. Except when I go to install it, it errors saying I require Outlook 2007. I have Outlook 2010 on the server and have no real way of getting 2007 on instead. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

RIM [does not support](http://us.blackberry.com/support/preinstallation/exchange.jsp#tab_tab_step2) Outlook on the same server with BES. They do [provide a link](http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=KB10493) to a possible solution.